# 4-pin connector identification

Tags: identification, connector

I need some help identifying the connector on the photos. The pitch is 2mm and looks very similar to a JST PA, but I'm not really sure it's one of those as it doesn't look exactly the official photos I can find (JST PA seems to have two "fins" on each side, but my connector has a single one, plus the latch design is different).

My Connector:
[image: Connector]
[image: Connector 2]

Board end:

[image: Board connector]

JST PA:

[image: Official PA]
<sub>(source: [jst-belgium.be](https://www.jst-belgium.be/images/products/pa_2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Board end part seems similar to Molex 0353630460, but without the two pins at the side (must be a family variant with those fins?). The connector seems to be Molex 0355070400. Compatible crimp would be Molex 0502128000.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It indeed looks closer to that one, but as you mention the connector looks lightly different. The clamp doesn't seem to be the same either (single "tab" on my PCB, versus dual "tab" for the 35507 family). I've gone through the whole Molex page looking for a component with all the same characteristics but can't find one. Maybe I'll buy some of those for testing though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/696358/311631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [VH Connector (High box type)](https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/vh-connector-high-box-type/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That can't be it; the design is very similar, but the pitch is grossly wrong (3.96mm vs. 2mm!).