# Identifying this board-to-wire connector

Tags: identification, connector

Does anyone know which exact connector this is? I can't find it in the JST catalogue and the seller doesn't respond. It has a 2mm pitch.

It doesn't fit in the JST-PH connector, the pins of this connector are centered and JST-PH pins are more to one side. It looks like the JST-PA, but the JST-PA seems to have thicker raised edges and ledges between the raised edge and the centered latch. I think it might just be another brand than JST.

[image: unknown board to wire connector, picture 1]

[image: unknown board to wire connector, picture 2]

[image: unknown board to wire connector, picture 3]

[image: unknown board to wire connector, picture 4]

Comment: Calling @DavideAndrea.

Comment: Also looks similar to JST PA family but not quite.

Comment: @Lundin ah, yes, meant the PA indeed. (XA is the same, but has a 2.5 mm pitch) Will edit the post, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554650/4-pin-connector-identification no answers though, so I'm not going to mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly found a match.  Variously called HY2.0, PH2.0 (but not the JST PH clone!), Grove connector, etc.

Possible duplicate thread: [Please help identify these 2.0mm pitch wafer wire to board connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/619269/please-help-identify-these-2-0mm-pitch-wafer-wire-to-board-connectors)

Besides Ali, they also show up on JLC's extended catalog: [WAFER-HY2.0-5PZZ | XUNPU | Wire To Board / Wire To Wire Connector | JLCPCB](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Xunpu-WAFER_HY2_05PZZ/C5359624), and I think, LCSC's Shenzen catalog: https://item.szlcsc.com/6173860.html

Comment: Thank you! AliExpress HY2.0 cables just came in and can confirm it is indeed that connector.