# Help identifying 6-pin roughly 2.54 mm pitch wire to board connector with latch

Tags: identification, connector

I am looking for the product which is the receptable of this connector so I need to know which brand and article this is. The connector is from a Neato Botvac D10 battery. Pitch is 2.5 or 2.54mm I think
[image: Figure 1]
Source: [Cameron Sino Akku für Neato 905-0596, 945-0356, 945-0373, Botvac D9, D10, D8, D9, Robotics D8 PN:Neato 205-0021, 205-0022, 205-0023, 205-0026, 945-0376, 945-0381, 945-0382 6400mAh | amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Cameron-905-0596-945-0356-945-0373-Robotics/dp/B0CHF4M3JD)

[image: Figure 2]
Source: [CAkku Neato BotVac D9- 205-0021 (Original) | ep-mediastore-ab.de](https://www.ep-mediastore-ab.de/akku-neato-botvac-d9-205-0021-original-p-71019.html)

One view of possible mate:

[image: Inline header photo]

Source: [Neato Botvac D8 PCB MCU Motherboard Main Board wifi D9 D10, caSino187 | eBay.com](https://www.ebay.com/itm/195320307079)

Edit:

- Added Citations for the pictures.
- Unfortunately I dont have pictures of the header.

Comment: I take it you don't have a picture of the header?

Comment: I can't tell you what it is, but maybe I can save you time by telling you what it isn't. Despite the similarities, it is not one of the following: JST XA, Molex 0351550600, Molex 0510670600, Molex Mini-lock, TE Economy power.

Comment: Related: the overall form, and pattern on the locking tab, are similar to this. However, the pitch is different. I didn't find any matching parts at the same manufacturer though; I suspect they copied their design from someone else, who may be what you're looking for. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696329/identifying-this-board-to-wire-connector

Comment: @TimWilliams - unfortunately I dont have pictures of the header. Thanks for the heads up regarding the citations and the link to the other SO-thread though! The connector seems probably rare most likely. I will just cut it off and use a standard Dupont/JST then :)